# Django / Wagtail: trying to add new children content to present on template

Tags: django, wagtail

I have 2 classes: `CandlePage` and `CandleIndexPage`.
the `CandlePage` is defined to describe the candle details.
the `CandleIndexPage` should present a list of Candles (`CandlePage` objects).

i need to add to the `CandleIndexPage` template a 'label' property for each `CandlePage` object.
i thought that it can be done with overriding the `get_context` method, but i was not able to do it on the 'children's level'.
happy to get any advice.

**models.py**

```
class CandleIndexPage(Page):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='+'
    )    
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full"),
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        # InlinePanel('candle_post', label="Light a Candle"),
    ]

class CandlePage(Page):
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['candlelabel'] = str(self.name) + "foo bar" + str(self.date)
        return context

    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)
    dedication = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='+'
    )   
    content_panels = [
        # PageChooserPanel('candle_index_page','CandleIndexPage'),
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('date'),
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('dedication'),

    ]
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        new_title = str(self.name) + str(self.date)
        self.title = new_title
        self.slug = slugify(new_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update that i resolved this by:
1. converting the queryset to a list:

```
candles = self(self.get_children().specific())
```

2. iterating the candles list and adding a 'label' attribute to each candle 'row' in the list
3. add the updated candles list as an attribute to the context object and returning the 'context'